# Selecting last date from one table if record exists in another table based on date range?

Tags: sql

I am trying to collect any records that are behind on a payment and would like to do this in one query.

This is the query that grabs the last time a payment was made:

```
SELECT t1.trans_code, t1.date, t1.balance, t1.amount
FROM trans T1
WHERE t1.date = 
    (SELECT max(date)
     FROM  trans T2
     WHERE T1.fileno = T2.fileno)
  AND T1.trans_code = 'PAY'
ORDER BY fileno
```

This is the query that grabs the list of candidates:

```
SELECT d.fileno, d.date, d.days, d.enddate, 
d.todo, m.def_fname, m.def_lname, a.addr, a.city, a.state, a.zip
FROM address AS a,
    diary AS d,
    main AS m
WHERE (m.fileno = d.fileno
         AND m.fileno = a.fileno) 
  AND (a.addrcode ='def'
         AND d.initials = 'PAY' 
         AND d.date >= {08-21-2014} 
         AND d.date <= {9-21-2014}) 
ORDER BY m.fileno
```

I only want the results of the 2nd query if no record exists after the first date in the second query (in this case 8/21) - this would mean they missed a payment.

`fileno` is unique and in pseudo code, my intentions are this:

Get a list of file numbers (fileno) and corresponding info (name, address, etc) from date x to date y in table named DIARY and only return those results if no payment exists for this file number after date x (in this case 9-21-2014) In table TRANS. Table ADDRESS holds the addresses for each file number.

Hope I explained it well enough - I just don't think my SQL is good enough to combine these 2 queries. Thanks in advance

Comment: what `brand` of database please? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? other?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT
      d.fileno
    , d.date
    , d.days
    , d.enddate
    , d.todo
    , m.def_fname
    , m.def_lname
    , a.addr
    , a.city
    , a.state
    , a.zip
FROM address AS a
      INNER JOIN main AS m
                  ON a.fileno = m.fileno
      INNER JOIN diary AS d
                  ON m.fileno = d.fileno
WHERE a.addrcode = 'def'
      AND d.initials = 'PAY'
      AND d.date >= '2014-08-21'
      AND d.date <= '2014-09-21'

      --  if no record exists after the "from" date above 
      AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT
                              NULL
                        FROM trans
                        WHERE trans.fileno = a.fileno
                              AND trans.trans_code = 'PAY'
                              AND trans.date > '2014-08-21'
                    )
ORDER BY
      m.fileno
```

Note I have used standard SQL join syntax, the the former "first" query is now amended (quite a bit) into a `NOT EXISTS` condition. This query doesn't need to aggregate, it is merely looking for the existence of a payment after the supplied date.

Oh, some people prefer to use `select null` in these exists queries but `select 1` or even `select *` will all work as alternatives.

Comment: tremendously helpful. I am using foxpro and using whatever I can to run the query, whether it's a report writer or converting the DBF tables to MSSQL or MYSQL.  Your answer has been of great benefit. Thanks